# Inductors in DC motor drivers

Tags: dc-motor, coil, motordriver

I've been making some research on DC motor drivers and I noticed that most medium power boards don't use inductors, but boards that can provide high current do, like this one:

https://www.cytron.io/p-60amp-7v-45v-smartdrive-dc-motor-driver-2-channels

What is the inductor used for in motor drivers?

Comment: Most boards that are powered from a battery will have some sort of inductor on them so that a Buck converter or a Boost converter can raise or lower the voltage of the battery to the correct voltage that a component needs.

Comment: I don't see any indication that your link uses an inductor. It is also not clear what size of inductor you are referring to since there can be tiny inductors used for auxilliary purposes around the board and very large DC-link inductors that can pass the entire motor current through them.

Comment: Of course you know, a motor driver has a nice big inductor on its output terminals...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your linked device can be used with a wide variety of DC voltages for various motors. There's on-board quite complex communication and motor speed controlling circuitry which needs its own stable operating voltage. To get that operating voltage properly from all possible motor supplying voltages a flexible switching power supply is needed. That power supply surely has inductors. Motor gets PWM signal, there's no inductors for motor current except possible radio interference limiting chokes.